# Problem installing processing: java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java

I'm trying install processing but i get the error java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I already re-install java from many tutorial but i get the same, could someone help me?

Comment: Processing uses it's own Java Runtime Environment, so usually there is no need to install/re-install Java.

Comment: @villares thank you, it's just like you say, i'm gonna use 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reported issue at https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5111 try to download an earlier version while this is not fixed.

Processing 3.3.3 should work fine.

UPDATE: Processing 3.3.5 is out and it's working fine on Ubuntu.