# How to install processing 3.3.4?

Tags: java

I can't install processing in Ubuntu 16, i think there are some issues with java, i have java 1.8.0_131 installed and i think there are ok (i've re-installed following this instructions: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/) but when i try install again processing always get the same message:
'java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

The steps i followed for install processing were:
1.- Download processing-3.3.4-linux64.tgz from the official page

2.- Copy and tar in the /opt folder

3.- Run ./processing in the /opt/processing-3.3.4 folder

could someone help me i'm new user in ubuntu

Update: I've find is a reported issue with processing 3.3.4 i tried with the previous version (3.3) and now is working, for more info: [Problem installing processing: java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923559/problem-installing-processing-java-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjl)

Comment: What "java 8 and 9" do you have, exactly - and how did you install them? How are you trying to install `processing`? Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 2):

**Installing Java 8:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

**Installing Processing 3.3.6**

1. Download Processing 3.3.6 tar.gz file from http://download.processing.org/processing-3.3.6-linux64.tgz
2. Copy the downloaded file to home directory
3. Open terminal and type  `tar xvfz processing-3.3.6-linux64.tgz` which will create a new file called processing-3.3.6
4. Now change to that directory using `cd processing-3.3.6`
5. Use `./processing` to run Processing 3.3.6

**To create a shortcut of program:**

1. Search for *Main Menu* and launch it (Download from Ubuntu Software if you don't have Main Menu application).
2. Select Accessories on left hand side
3. Click on New Item button .
4. Enter *Processing* as name.
5. Enter */home/aditya/processing-3.3.6/processing* as command and click OK.
6. Now search for *Processing* and launch it.
7. In the launcher Right Click the icon and select Lock to Launcher.

Done! 
Now whenever you want to launch Processing, just click on this icon.

All The Best!